# Usage of Spring Security in console Java Application

Tags: java, encoding, spring-security, console-application

I'm building a simple console application which uses nice stack of frameworks(Hibernate, Spring), but found myself struggling with auth/reg issues. Usually for web projects I would use Spring Security framework, restrict some URL add configure login page which is completely processed by the framework automatically. But my console application contains 2 issues:

1. Storing encoded passwords in a database
2. Using User Service to configure Spring to work with my database

1st problem can be solved using some password encoder and specifying it in a spring-security configuration file like this

```
<beans:bean class="myconsoleapp.util.PasswordUtil" id="passwordEncoder" factory-method="getPasswordEncoder"/>
```

and later specify encoder in authentication manager

```
<authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userService">
            <password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder"/>
        </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

2nd problem seems to be more complex. In my service class I've implemented **UserDetailsService** spring security interface and have overridden **loadUserByUsername** method like this

```
@Service("userService")
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService, UserDetailsService {
public AuthorizedUser loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = repository.getByEmail(email.toLowerCase());
        return new AuthorizedUser(user);
    }
}
```

And my AuthorizedUser class has a constructor like this

```
public class AuthorizedUser extends org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User {
private User user;
public AuthorizedUser(User user) {
        super(user.getEmail(), user.getPassword(), user.isEnabled(), true, true, true, user.getRoles());
        this.user= user;
    }
}
```

Finally we're close to the question.. How can I use all that stuff providing email and password input from the console?? I see it like that:

```
System.out.println("Enter email:");
String userEmail = inputStream.readLine();
System.out.println("Enter your password");
String userPasspord = inputStream.readLine();
userService.//<-What method should I use here?
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that you can access the [authentication manager](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.3.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/AuthenticationManager.html) bean, you can check the credentials something like this:

```java
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userEmail, userPassword);
try {
    authenticationManager.authenticate(token);
    System.out.println("Login successful!");
} catch (BadCredentialsException e) {
    System.out.println("Bad credentials!");
}
```